# Android SurfaceView and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview

I would like to have **a `SurfaceView` sitting on top of a `TextView`** so i can display various different solid lines on top of the text.

All the tutorials I have seen online don't use `Fragment`s, which to me is a problem as I have my layout designed in a fragment.  **How do I go about setting up this surface view from my fragment**?

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't believe you can have a `SurfaceView` "sit on top of" a `TextView`. The `SurfaceView` will erase everything in the view hierarchy underneath it so that you can see the separate window containing the surface it provides.

Second, you don't need a `SurfaceView` at all. Create a sub-class of `TextView` and override it's `onDraw` method. Draw your lines or whatever else with the `Canvas` passed there.

Edit:

```
public class TextWithLinesView extends TextView {
    // ...
    // Constructor with Context parameter, etc.
    // ...
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // Use the Canvas to draw whatever you'd like here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you have a textView sit on top of a textView then or can you have text and lines together in a single textView?

Comment: @AllanMacmillan You can draw whatever you'd like inside any class that extends a `View` by simply overriding `onDraw`. I added example code in the answer.

Comment: Do I pass a canvas with the required lines/colours etc to the TextViewWithLines when I call onDraw? or when I call onDraw should it then run the code in the onDraw function.  SOrry just trying to get my head around what exactly happens

Comment: @AllanMacmillan You shouldn't call `onDraw` at all. It will be called by the OS at an appropriate time with the same `Canvas` that was used to draw the `TextView`.